# svg element clips translated elements

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, translate

With the following code, the translated `rect`s are clipped by the svg element, based on their position before translate, even though I have `overflow="visible"`. I want to do it this way because I want to animate properties of the translated `rect`s. It would be fiddly to do it in other ways and I don't feel like I should have to. Why is this happening and how to solve?

````
#tunnel{width:800px;height:800px; background-color: aquamarine;}

</style></head><body>
    <svg id="tunnel" width="800" height="800" overflow="visible">
        <defs>
          <mask id="hole1">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="800" cy="800" r="150"/>
          </mask>
          <mask id="hole2">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="800" cy="800" r="300"/>
          </mask>
          
            <defs>
                <radialGradient id="myGradient">
                <stop offset="25%" stop-color="red" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
                </radialGradient>
            </defs>
        </defs>
        <g  transform="translate(-400,-400)">
            <g  transform="translate(150,150)">
                <rect id="t1" width="1600" height="1600" fill="url(#myGradient)" mask="url(#hole1)"/>
            </g>
            <rect id="t2" width="1600" height="1600" fill="url(#myGradient)" mask="url(#hole2)"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
</body></html>```
````

Comment: Try this: translate the <rect>, wrap it in a <g> and mask the group